# Any executable or library to Dump DOM tree in webkit?

Tags: parsing, dom, webkit, html-parsing, rendering

Similar to DumpRenderTree tool which dumps render tree onto disk, is there any tool which dumps the DOM tree (parse tree) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can tweak the DumpRenderTree tool itself to get the DOM tree. I modified the "String externalRepresentation(Frame*, RenderAsTExtBEhavior) "function in RenderTreeAsTExt.cpp file and added below code at the beginning of the function. This worked for me.

```
if (!renderer || !renderer->isBox())
    return String();
Node* n = renderer->node();
n->showTreeForThis();
return String();
```